# flutter problem : how to create a Pin code field like this?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

how to create a Pin code field like this , I dont know how to create pin code field ui like this.
In plugin I dont found out like this.

[image]

[image]

please help me,
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use this [library](https://pub.dev/packages/pin_code_fields)

```
import 'package:pin_code_fields/pin_code_fields.dart';


PinCodeTextField(
  length: 6,
  obscureText: false,
  animationType: AnimationType.fade,
  pinTheme: PinTheme(
    shape: PinCodeFieldShape.box,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
    fieldHeight: 50,
    fieldWidth: 40,
    activeFillColor: Colors.white,
  ),
  animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
  backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade50,
  enableActiveFill: true,
  errorAnimationController: errorController,
  controller: textEditingController,
  onCompleted: (v) {
    print("Completed");
  },
  onChanged: (value) {
    print(value);
    setState(() {
      currentText = value;
    });
  },
  beforeTextPaste: (text) {
    print("Allowing to paste $text");
    //if you return true then it will show the paste confirmation dialog. Otherwise if false, then nothing will happen.
    //but you can show anything you want here, like your pop up saying wrong paste format or etc
    return true;
  },
)
```

[image]